# Managed array of pixels is faster than using pointers?

Tags: c#

I saw this article recently while exploring various ways to work with images at a pixel-level.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16403/Fast-Pointerless-Image-Processing-in-NET

And the author mentions that

> What of the performance cost of using a managed array instead of pointers? Wouldn't using a managed array be slower than using pointers? It might surprise you, but based on my tests, the answer is no. In my tests, have found that the array method is at least 10% faster than the pointer method.

My first attempt at working with images at a pixel level was using the `GetPixel`/`SetPixel` methods, which was incredibly slow. Then I was directed to [this link](http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/13/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-i/) and it was considerably faster.

I haven't tried the method described in the article but can anyone support it? Or perhaps it is only faster under certain conditions?

Comment: As always it depends. If you use unsafe code the JITer will be able to do less optimizatons. So you could be faster with an array in some cases. But unsafe can still pay off if you get a direct pointer to the image from unmanaged code. If you want a managed array you need to copy it modify it and then copy it back. That does cost you quite a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends quite a bit on how you are accessing the arrays.

If you are using the length of the array in a loop, the compiler recognises this and knows that it doesn't have to check the bounds of the index, as the loop itself makes it impossible for the index to be out of bounds. This way of accessing arrays will be close in performance to using pointers.

If you are accessing the array with an arbitrary index, the compiler has to add the code that checks the bounds of the index, which will add a few instructions to every access. This way of accessing arrays will be slower than using pointers.

It also depends on how efficient the code is that uses pointers. In the end a pointer is always used to access the array data even if you are using an index to access the array, so it's always possible to write pointer code that is at least as efficient as the code accessing the array by index.

Also, it depends on how much processing you are doing. Using marshalling to move the data from and to an image means that you move all the data twice already. If you are doing little processing, that can never be as fast as accessing the data in place.

---

Note: The method used to marshal the data in the article only works if the `Stride` value is positive. If the image is stored upside down in memory (common for Bitmap files), then the `Stride` value is negative, and the calculated data size will be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Perf differences of 10% are not statistically meaningful.  Array access in managed code tends to be slower due to the added out-of-bounds check.  Which can be optimized away by the jitter, but that's not so easy with a two-dimensional structure that you access as a single-dimension array.  Pointers are unsafe primarily because they are used without such a check.

But code speed becomes meaningless when you start to address large amounts of RAM, like the amount required to store a non-trivially sized bitmap.  The perf of such code is throttled by the bandwidth of the memory bus.  Which is *many* times slower than the rate at which the processor can consume data.  One thing that now starts to become important is that you access data in a way that optimizes the use of the L1 processor cache.  Which is the natural way you access bitmap pixels, you'll want them in column (X) order, not row order.  In other words, the X variable needs to be the inner loop, the Y needs to be the outer.

In all likelihood, you are already going as fast as you can, particularly if you copied code that carries a claim like this.  The only way to prove it is to actually write the code that uses pointers, which requires C#, and compare.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of considering how much memory a piece of code might be needing when it comes to performance.